# The preLaunch 'C/C++:gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1

Tags: c++, debugging, visual-studio-code

When ever I debug my code in Visual Studio Code I get

> The preLaunch 'C/C++:gcc.exe build active file' terminated with exit code -1

I built my file using cpp.exe,
here is the launch.json file :

```
{
// Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
// Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
// For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "gcc.exe - Build and debug active file",
        "type": "cppdbg",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "C://code//program.exe",
        "args": [],
        "stopAtEntry": false,
        "cwd": "${workspaceFolder}",
        "environment": [],
        "externalConsole": false,
        "MIMode": "gdb",
        "miDebuggerPath": "C:\\MinGW\\bin\\gdb.exe",
        "setupCommands": [
            {
                "description": "Enable pretty-printing for gdb",
                "text": "-enable-pretty-printing",
                "ignoreFailures": true
            }
        ],
        "preLaunchTask": "C/C++: gcc.exe build active file"
    }
]
}
```

Comment: your build task is failing, presumably due to errors in your code, please show a [mre]

Comment: @AlanBirtles I can't even debug Hello World program

Comment: Doesn't mean you can't provide a [mre]. If you are a c++ novice I'd recommend using visual studio as it is much easier to setup than code, mingw has various issues too

Comment: @AlanBirtles No matter what code I try to debug it shows the same error.